# Finding "build_config.json" file to fix kite installation

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab, kite

I am trying to install kite on jupyter-lab 3.0.5 using a Linux terminal but the server extension is not working. Instead, I am getting this error message:

```
Server Extension Unreachable

The jupyterlab-kite extension will not work because the jupyter-kite server extension could not be reached.

To fix this, please ensure the jupyter-kite server extension is installed and active (`jupyter serverextension list`), then restart the JupyterLab process.
```

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it using:

```
pip install "jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2"
```

but I cannot get the server extension to work. When I try to enable the server extension, I get an error as shown below.

```
thamu@thamu-PC:~$ jupyter server extension enable jupyter_kite
Enabling: jupyter_kite
- Writing config: /usr/etc/jupyter
    - Validating jupyter_kite...
      jupyter_kite 2.0.2 OK
      X Validation failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/etc'
```

I have found what I think is a solution on [GITHUB here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8122) but I have not installed Jupyter using Anaconda so this address (`<conda_root>/share/jupyter/lab/settings/build_config.json`) is not the same as on my computer to delete the `build_config.json` file. Does anyone know how else I could find this file in order to enable the kite server?

Comment: What about `jupyter server extension list` or using the LSP extension?

Comment: @krassowski, I ran it above and added the output.